# Interchanging the order of integrations results in different answers

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

Suppose that we want to calculate the following integral:
$$\iint_{s+r<c}\lambda\exp(-\lambda s)\alpha\exp(-\alpha r)\delta(t-s-r)d(s,r)$$
where $\delta(.)$ is the delta dirac function and $t$ and $c$ are constants where $t<c$. When I do the integration first over $r$ and then over $s$, I get:
$$\int_0^c\int_0^{c-s}\lambda\exp(-\lambda s)\alpha\exp(-\alpha r)\delta(t-s-r)drds$$
$$=\int_0^c\lambda\exp(-\lambda s)\alpha\exp(-\alpha(t-s))ds$$
$$=\alpha\lambda\exp(-\alpha t)\int_0^c\exp(-(\lambda-\alpha)s)ds$$
$$\frac{\alpha\lambda}{\lambda-\alpha}exp(-\alpha t)[1-\exp(-(\lambda-\alpha)c)]$$

But, when I change the order of integrations, I get a different result:
$$\int_0^c\int_0^{c-r}\lambda\exp(-\lambda s)\alpha\exp(-\alpha r)\delta(t-s-r)dsdr$$
$$=\int_0^c\lambda\exp(-\lambda(t-r))\alpha\exp(-\alpha r)dr$$
$$=\alpha\lambda\exp(-\lambda t)\int_0^c\exp(-(\alpha-\lambda)r)dr$$
$$\frac{\alpha\lambda}{\lambda-\alpha}\exp(-\lambda t)[1-\exp(-(\alpha-\lambda)c)]$$

Is there any problem with my calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must consider carefully the case $t-s<0$:
$$
\int_0^{c-s}e^{-\alpha r}\delta(t-s-r)dr=e^{-\alpha (t-s)}\theta(t-s),
$$
where $\theta$ is Heaviside function.

Comment: This is true in general, but as we have $\delta(t-s-r)$, the overall integral has answer only when $t=s+r$ which implies that $t-s<0$ cannot happen. So the Heaviside function is not necessary.

Comment: When you subsequently integrate over $s$ from $0$ to $c$, you can of course have $s>t$, because $t<c$. In other words: the outer integral should run from $0$ to $t$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The outer integration should run from $0$ to $t$. Thanks.